# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock in gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I looked at any other questions but can't find my own solution! I setting up a CI in gitlab and use the gitlab's shared runner. In build stage I used docker image as base image but when i use `docker` command it says :

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I looked at [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) topic but still don't understand what should I do?

> .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

job_1:
  image: python:3.6
  stage: test
  script:
    - sh ./sh_script/install.sh
    - python manage.py test -k

job_2:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker info
  script:
    - docker build -t my-docker-image .
```

I know that the gitlab runner must registered to use `docker` and share `/var/run/docker.sock`! But how to do this when using the gitlab own runner?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ahh, that's my lovely topic - using `docker` for `gitlab ci`. The problem you are experiencing is better known as `docker-in-docker`.

Before configuring it, you may want to read this brilliant post: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

That will give you a bit of understanding what is the problem and which solution best fits you. Generally there are 2 major approaches: actual installation of `docker` daemon inside `docker` and sharing host's daemon to containers. Which approach to choose - depends on your needs.

In `gitlab` you can go in several ways, I will just share our experience.

**Way 1 - using `docker:dind` as a service.**

It is pretty simple to setup. Just add `docker:dind` as a shared service to your `gitlab-ci.yml` file and use `docker:latest` image for your jobs.

```
image: docker:latest  # this sets default image for jobs
services:
  - docker:dind
```

**Pros**:

- simple to setup.
- simple to run - your source codes are available by default to your job in `cwd` because they are being pulled directly to your docker runner

**Cons**: you have to configure docker registry for that service, otherwise you will get your `Dockerfile`s built from scratch each time your pipeline starts. As for me, it is unacceptable, because can take more than an hour depending on the number of containers you have.

**Way 2 - sharing `/var/run/docker.sock` of host docker daemon**

We setup our own docker executor with docker daemon and shared the socket by adding it in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file. Thus we made our machine's docker daemon available to `docker cli` inside containers. **Note** - you DONT need **privileged** mode for executor in this case.

After that we can use both `docker` and `docker-compose` in our custom docker images. Moreover, we dont need special docker registry because in this case we share executor's registry among all containers.

**Cons**

You need to somehow pass sources to your containers in this case, because you get them mounted only to docker executor, but not to containers, launched from it. We've stopped on cloning them with command like `git clone $CI_REPOSITORY_URL --branch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --single-branch /project`

Comment: In the second way, how can I access to the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`?

Comment: As I mentioned for the second approach, we use our own docker executor (VPS service). If you use provided by `gitlab`, you wont be able to share the socket, sorry

Comment: How do we make this configurations on a kubernets runner
created using gitlab.com

Comment: Hi @grapes please help me on the same solution, please check the link once https://stackoverflow.com/q/64587625/3946958

Comment: sure this is nice, but if you are just a user and the admin refuses to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried adding this to my helm chart deployment under runner configuration and docker started working, use this if you deployed your runner in Kubernetes.

```
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "ubuntu:18.04"
        privileged = true
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "docker"
          mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Run Gitlab Runner (With Privileges)

It seems that even with the additional privileges provided to the Bitnami gitlab-runner container, it is still encountering permission issues when trying to access the Docker daemon socket.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check the ownership and permissions of the Docker socket file on your macOS machine. Open a terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
   ```

   Ensure that the file is owned by the **`root`** user and the **`staff`** group. The permissions should allow read and write access for the owner and group.
2. Adjust the ownership and permissions of the Docker socket file if necessary. Run the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo chown root:staff /var/run/docker.sock
   sudo chmod 660 /var/run/docker.sock
   ```
3. Restart the Bitnami gitlab-runner container with the updated ownership and permissions of the Docker socket. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo docker run -it --user=root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner bitnami/gitlab-runner
   ```

If you still unable to run the previous command,,

Run this final command to ensure Gitlab-runner container is running with root privilege, allowing it to access the Docker Daemon Socket.

By specifying **`--user=root`** in the command, you ensure that the Bitnami gitlab-runner container runs with root privileges, which should allow it to access the Docker daemon socket.

With these steps, the Bitnami gitlab-runner container should be able to connect to the Docker daemon and execute Docker-related tasks without encountering permission denied errors.

```
sudo docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner bitnami/gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me. specifically the `DOCKER_HOST` variable was the final straw to get success. couldn't tell you why though, sorry!

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

# github runs docker right out of the box
# gitlab... not so much apparently
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/70813945/5563327
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add socket as volume as well:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Builder"
  url = "https://gitlab.xxx.eu"
  id = 0
  token = "XXX"
  token_obtained_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["gitlab-shared-cache:/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
```