# Run a multi-container application tests in the CI process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I have a Laravel application which has some Integration Tests and this project has Dockerized using Docker Compose and it's consisted of 5 containers: `php-fpm`, `mysql`, `redis`, `nginx` and the `workspace` which have `php-cli` and `composer` installed in itself (just like **Laradock**). I want to run the tests while the `test stage` is running in my CI process. I have to mention that my CI Server is GitLab CI.

Basically, I run the tests on my local system by running the following commands in my terminal:

```sh
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "docker_backend" with driver "bridge"
Creating network "docker_frontend" with driver "bridge"
Creating redis     ... done
Creating workspace ... done
Creating mysql     ... done
Creating php-fpm   ... done
Creating nginx     ... done

$ docker-compose exec workspace bash
// now, I have logged in to workspace container

$ cd /var/www/app
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

........                                                            8 / 8 (100%)

Time: 38.1 seconds, Memory: 28.00MB

OK (8 tests, 56 assertions)
```

Here is my question: **How I can run these tests in test stage while there is no running container? What're the Best Practices in this case?**

I also followed [this documentation of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-shell-executor), but it seems that is not OK to use Docker-in-Docker or Docker Socket Binding.

Comment: Do your tests use resources from the other containers? I.e. do they connect to the database?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes, they do. Some of the tests need a testing database to run migrations and working with dummy data. Also, redis container should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is absolutely ok to run `docker-in-docker` with gitlab ci. This is a greate way if you dont want or dont need to dive into `kubernetes`. Sharing docker socket of course somehow lowers the isolation level, but as far as you mostly run your jobs on your VPS containers, I personally dont find this issue critical.

I've answered similar question some time ago in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53968888/10524386) post.

Comment: I read about this in one of Docker-in-Docker contributor's blog that we should not use DinD for CI or testing environment.
https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: When you **share socket**, I mean `/var/run/docker.sock`, it is not pure **docker in docker**, and it is exactly what is written in that article. You are using host's docker daemon.

Comment: And you dont need priviledged mode when sharing a socket

Comment: It was about the DinD, so it's not OK to use `docker-in-docker`. On the other hand, I have some containers that are running on the host machine and mounting the socket may affect them. I want to know what're the best practices about the running tests in multi-containers projects.