Gitlab - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
it's been a couple of weeks now that the previously working CI job in Gitlab is not working anymore. Here's the error
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

This is my CI yaml file
api_server_build_and_deploy:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/ci_deploy
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind

  environment:
    name: Staging
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $DOCKER_REGISTRY
  script:
    # omitted for brevity

and this is the base dockerfile
FROM node:20.10.0-alpine3.19

# installing essential environment
RUN apk add zip
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add docker-cli bash

# also installing angular
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@15.2.10 # may not be needed

# installing ssh
RUN command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --no-cache openssh )

VOLUME "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

This used to work fine, has anything changed that requires some further config changes?
Thanks

Seems like your Gitlab runner cannot acces the docker engine. You should check whther or not someone modified your runner

it's the online version, is it configurable as well?

If they are not accessible then you might want to take a look at similar questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968749/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-in-gitlab-ci and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806828/why-gitlab-runner-throws-is-the-docker-daemon-running

adding variables:
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
is the answer! thank you!
